# How do I compare a range to an array?

Tags: ruby

How do I see if an array matches a range?

```
[1..3] == [1,2,3] # => false
```

I've also tried

```
[1..3].to_a == [1,2,3] # => false
```

but I'm stumped. Is there any way to coerce a range into an array so I can compare it with one?

Comment: Question is not clear. Define when it is that a range matches an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ah! Turns out I was getting confused on the syntax.

```
arr = [1..3] # Actually sets an array with a range as the first element
arr[0] # => 1..3
```

What I needed was this:

```
(1..3).to_a == [1,2,3] # => true
```

Comment: `(1..3).to_a` can also be written `[*1..3] => [1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
2.1.1 :006 > [1..3].class
 => Array 
2.1.1 :007 > (1..3).class
 => Range 
2.1.1 :008 > (1..3).to_a == [1,2,3]
 => true
```

hope that solves your issue